# How to make sbt to look for scala dist in local maven repository?

Tags: scala, sbt

I managed to build my own scala distribution and I published it locally into maven repository (`~/.m2/repository`). But when I set sbt to use that version, it looks only in local ivy, typesafe-ivy-releases, Maven Central and sonatype-snaphshots. It does not look in local maven repository, even though I specified it in `project/plugins.sbt` as follows:

```
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://" + Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/.m2/repository"
```

Also I tried:

```
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

Of course, I could move the files from maven repo to ivy one by hand, but that seems too bad. What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SBT you can set Scala home directly and don't need a maven repository:

scalaHome := Some(file("/path/to/scala"))

Source: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Local-Scala